# How to make multiline numbered heading?

Tags: sectioning

is it possible to have for example sections numbered in row above ? kind of like chapters work

instead of having:

> 1 Section alpha
>
> 2 Section beta

i'd like to have

> Section 1
>
> Alpha
>
> Section 2
>
> Beta

is it possible to achieve with generic heading style?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Perhaps you can update your post to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. It just speeds up getting answers your way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the package `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[display]
 {\large\bfseries}
 {Section \thesection}
 {.5ex}
 {\Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

Some text before.

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

Text.

\section*{A numberless section}

Other text.

\end{document}
```

Adjust at will; the size of "Section 1" should be less than the title's size, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: great! this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks a **lot** !

Answer (score 1):

With the following code I am able to produce this:

[image: Result obtained]

Is it what you want?

```
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\section*{Section \thesection \\ Alpha}

\addtocounter{section}{1}
\section*{Section \thesection \\ Beta}
```

If you want to automate it you can define a new command before the `\begin{document}` command:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}%
\section*{Section \thesection \\ #1}}
```

And use this new command instead of the usual `\section` command

```
\mysection{Alpha}

\mysection{Beta}
```

NOTE: This has been obtained using the `article` class.